# uitextfield of custom table cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitextfield, custom-cell

I am creating a table with three different types of custom cell, One of them, one custom cell is having `UITextField`. I create two rows using this custom cell. I set tag and delegate for textfields of both row.
My problem is, when I scroll the table, these rows with textfields move up and disappear from the screen, when scroll down, that time my app gets crash.
I get an error like

```
-[CellImageViewController txtField]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0ea5e0
```

Here is my code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
if (indexPath.row == 0 )
        {
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[CellWithTextFieldViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID] autorelease];
            }

            cell.txtField.tag =1;

            cell.txtField.delegate = self;
            cell.txtField.text = @"kjfkd";
            }


            return cell;

        }
        else if(indexPath.row==1)
        {
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[CellWithTextFieldViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID] autorelease];
            }

           cell.txtField.tag = 2;
           cell.txtField.text = @"glk";
           cell.txtField.delegate = self;

          return cell;
     }
```

Any one have idea about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

you have different type of cells, so you need to use a cellIdentifier different for each one.

Try this:

```
customOrNormalCell *cell [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
if(!cell){
    cell = [[CellWithTextFieldViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.row]];
}
```

With this code, each cellIdentifier will be 1,2,3,4... (All different)

I'm pretty sure that it will solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

create `UITextField` before create `UITableView` and  Add your Textfield object in cell Content view

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:yourTxtFieldOblect];
```

Comment: yeah.. I did this but still gets crash

Comment: create one custom method and put initialization code of UITextField and this method call before create UITableView (Put Only initialization code not to add) and **Add it to cell contentView**...try it ..may be solve ur problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be reusing a cell of a different type. 
Try making sure which kind of class the cell you are reusing is before trying to access it's properties.

Answer (score 0):

why you are define cell for each row?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d",indexPath.row];
 CellWithTextFieldViewController  *cell = (CellWithTextFieldViewController *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


  if(cell == nil)
  {
    cell =[[[CellWithTextFieldViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

    cell.txtField.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.txtField.text = [SET TEXT FROM ARRAY];
    cell.txtField.delegate = self;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced this problem in my project.

just try this:

Disabled the scrolling property in Tableview and create a scrollview.Then add your Tableview in your scrollview.

```
UITableView  *table=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 976, 395) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[table setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
UIScroll *scroll=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(24, 168, 978, 395)];
 [table setScrollEnabled:NO];

[scroll addSubview:table];
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
[scroll sendSubviewToBack:table];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     static NSString *cellIdentifier= @"Cell";

    CellWithTextFieldViewController *cell = (CellWithTextFieldViewController *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[CellWithTextFieldViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }

        cell.txtField.tag =indexPath.row+1;

        cell.txtField.delegate = self;
        cell.txtField.text = @"kjfkd";

        return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

While scrolling tableView your cell is getting reused. Thats why textField is disappearing. Try to use different  cell id for different custom cells. Dont forget to give the same id in nib file for cell identifier

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
static NSString *customCellOne = @"customCell1";
static NSString *customCellTwo = @"customCell2";
UITableViewCell *cell =nil;



if (0 == indexPath.row)
{
    cell = (CustomCellOne *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customCellOne];

    if (nil == cell)
    {
        // Create custom cell one and do what ever you want

    }
}
else if (1 == indexPath.row)
{
    cell=(CustomCellTwo *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customCellTwo];

    if (nil == cell)
    {
         // Create custom cell two and do what ever you want       
    }

}

return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know,may be when reused the cell,the textfield delegate was released.
may be you can set the

```
  textfield.deleagate = self;
```

in CellWithTextFieldViewController.m